# How to skip repeated content from searching using simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, simple-html-dom, html-parser

I want to skip certain repeated content from HTML page using simple HTML dom class. Suppose as you can see on this link: `http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Category:Agriculture_Bookshelf` `Forestry` comes 2 times.

One in the upper portion named `SD Forestry` and in below with only `Forestry`. So these both have the same links named: `/wiki/Forestry` which is creating much problem for me.

Now, when i iterate this in foreach loop using: `$subhtml->find('a[href^="/wiki/"]')` it finds all those links from the page and having the link like this but I want unique links only means with out any repetitions in them.

On the same page, look for `Horticulture` and `Horticulture (Bookshelf)` both of them have same links in them like : `/wiki/Horticulture_(Bookshelf)`. But I want to treat them as once so the function or certain piece of PHP code skip repeated portion from the HTML content.

So when `find` function starts, it will simple skip repeated ones and treat them as ones only.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="bodyContent">
    <div id="contentSub"> </div>
    <div id="mw-content-text" lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
      <p>LoC classification S <a href="/w/index.php?title=Agriculture&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Agriculture (page does not exist)">Agriculture</a> 32863 </p>
      <ul>
        <li> Conservation </li>
        <li> SB <a href="/w/index.php?title=Plant_culture&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Plant culture (page does not exist)">Plant culture</a> </li>
        <li> sb 300 <a href="/wiki/Horticulture_(Bookshelf)" title="Horticulture (Bookshelf)">Horticulture</a> </li>
        <li> SD <a href="/wiki/Forestry" title="Forestry">Forestry</a> </li>
        <li> SF <a href="/w/index.php?title=Animal_culture&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Animal culture (page does not exist)">Animal culture</a> </li>
        <li> SF 600 <a href="/w/index.php?title=Veterinary_medicine&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Veterinary medicine (page does not exist)">Veterinary medicine</a> </li>
        <li> SH <a href="/w/index.php?title=Aquaculture&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Aquaculture (page does not exist)">Aquaculture</a> </li>
        <li> SK <a href="/w/index.php?title=Hunting_%26_fishing&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Hunting &amp; fishing (page does not exist)">Hunting &amp; fishing</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <div lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <div id="mw-pages">
          <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          <div lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
            <h3>F</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/wiki/Forestry" title="Forestry">Forestry</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h3>H</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/wiki/Horticulture_(Bookshelf)" title="Horticulture (Bookshelf)">Horticulture (Bookshelf)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the urls with `/wiki/` without duplicates, just point them onto the anchor `a` then a simple loop is just needed. Consider this example:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$urls = array();
$url = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Category:Agriculture_Bookshelf';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($value->href, '/wiki/') !== false && strpos($value->href, '/wiki/Category:') === false) {
        $urls[urldecode($value->href)] = $key;
    }
}

$urls = array_values(array_flip($urls));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($urls);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /wiki/Horticulture_(Bookshelf)
    [1] => /wiki/Forestry
    [2] => /wiki/Special:Categories
    [3] => /wiki/Main_Page
    [4] => /wiki/Gutenberg:Contact_Information
    [5] => /wiki/Gutenberg:Project_Gutenberg_Needs_Your_Donation
    [6] => /wiki/Gutenberg:Privacy_policy
    [7] => /wiki/Gutenberg:About
    [8] => /wiki/Gutenberg:General_disclaimer
)
```

Comment: `<div id="mw-content-text" lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
      <div lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <div id="mw-pages">
          <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          <div lang="en" dir="ltr" class="mw-content-ltr">
            <h3>F</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/wiki/Forestry" title="Forestry">Forestry</a></li>
            </ul>
            <h3>H</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/wiki/Horticulture_(Bookshelf)" title="Horticulture (Bookshelf)">Horticulture (Bookshelf)</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

Comment: So simply I would like to have the urls from both upper and lower HTML code without repeation.

Comment: I meant to say I want to have only and only unique URLS within `/wiki/`

Comment: thank you very much it works fine for me but I am having some other problems as well. please can you overlook this question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346381/scrapping-code-is-not-working-as-expected-inserting-repeated-data-in-the-databa`

Comment: That is too my main problem so far I am having with this code. please help me getting through this.

Comment: another problem please. from this url: `http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Children%27s_Periodicals_(Bookshelf)` I having a result from which I do not need these links: `[6] => /wiki/Category:Children%27s_Bookshelf
    [7] => /wiki/Category:Periodicals_Bookshelf
    [8] => /wiki/Category:General_Works_Bookshelf`. That is also my major problem which I tried posting in my previous question as well.  I do not want these links in my code nor I want to process them. They are different on each pages. but anything associated with `/wiki/Category:......` should be omitted at every cost from all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure If I understand your question 100% but....

Can you keep track of all urls with an array?

```
$outputedUrls = array();
```

When you echo the urls, push them into the array. But, before you echo them, you should check that the url does not exist in $outputedUrls.

```
if (!in_array($url, $outputedUrls)) {
    echo $url;
    $outputedUrls[] = $url;
}
```